# Inverse Kinematics, spins wildly

Tags: rigging, bones

I am trying to make an inverse Kinematics between the leg IK.L and the lower leg.L, thsi also has to have a pole target of Knee.L

[image: before]

The problem is as soon as I move the leg IK.L part the rest of the leg starts spinning uncontrollably, and even if I try to move it back to the starting position it just continues to spin

[image: After]

I really need help on this as an hour long tedious search has turned up nothing relating to my problem, these are the settings for the IK.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Have you followed the rigging tutorial from BlenderGuru? I believe he covers this issue. Warning: it's an hour and a half of video. I think your issue is covered in the 3rd video. http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/introduction-to-rigging/

Answer (score 4):

You have to unparent the IK bone from the rest of the rig. Once you have the bone selected in edit mode go to the armature settings and at the top of that menu there's the parent options choose 'clear parent'. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you enable ik have a driver that bends the bone like how you want this should help. Also set the chain length to 2 and play around with the pole angle.